# Why is list of structs not IEnumerable<object>?

Tags: c#, object, struct, ienumerable

Running the [below program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwYxfB) gives the following output:

> Class is object.
> Class list is IEnumerable<object>.
> Struct is object.
> Struct list is not IEnumerable<object>.

That implies that a struct instance is an `object` but that a list of struct instances is not `IEnumerable<object>`. Why is that so?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public struct MyStruct
    {}
    
    public class MyClass
    {}
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Check if a class instance is an object
        MyClass classInstance = new MyClass();
        if (classInstance is object) Console.WriteLine("Class is object.");
        else Console.WriteLine("Class is no object.");
        
        // Check if a list of class instances is IEnumerable<object>
        List<MyClass> classList = new List<MyClass>() {classInstance};
        if (classList is IEnumerable<object>) Console.WriteLine("Class list is IEnumerable<object>");
        else Console.WriteLine("Class list is not IEnumerable<object>");

        // Check if a struct instance is an object
        MyStruct structInstance = new MyStruct();
        if (structInstance is object) Console.WriteLine("Struct is object.");
        else Console.WriteLine("Struct is no object.");
        
        // Check if a list of structs is IEnumerable<object>
        List<MyStruct> structList = new List<MyStruct>() {structInstance};
        if (structList is IEnumerable<object>) Console.WriteLine("Struct list is IEnumerable<object>");
        else Console.WriteLine("Struct list is not IEnumerable<object>");       
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking at *variance* and [Variance in Generic Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces): "Variance in generic interfaces is supported for reference types only. Value types do not support variance.". This is primarily because structs can only be thought of as objects when they're boxed but here in these interfaces the structs aren't boxed.

Comment: One related thing to be aware of is that using a `foreach` loop [inserts a silent explicit cast](https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/) to the loop variable type, so you *can* do `foreach (object obj in structList)` - that will perform a boxing operation on each element.

Comment: A struct isn't an object but can be boxed into one. In all generic types, not just `IEnumerable<T>`, an inheritance relation between the type parameters, eg `Person` and `Customer` doesn't imply an inheritance relation between the concrete types, eg `List<Person>` and `List<Customer>`. You can only use derived or base classes interfaces through variance. Variance in turn is possible when it's safe to do so without side effects. Boxing is definitely a side effect.

Comment: If you need to be able to treat both the same, you could look at the non-generic `IEnumerable` instead.

Comment: In most cases making the calling method itself generic removes the need for `object` and type checking. `IEnumerable<object>` is rarely needed and almost always a smell. Generics were created to *avoid* boxing